# Nonlinear ODE in 1D

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am having trouble solving this ODE in one dimension:
$$ au''(x) + b|u'(x)|^2 + cu(x)+ df(x) = 0$$
where $a,b,c$ are constants and $f(x)$ is a given force term, which is periodic and continuous.

I would like to look for analytic solutions if we can, I think it fits well to the theory of viscosity solution of Hamilton-Jacobi equation, but I have no idea how to find it explicitly. Also I will be truly appreciate if anyone can come up with a way finding it numerically.

Comment: Are you looking for an analytic solution?

Comment: Yes I would like to know analytic solutions it we can.

Comment: Is $u$ a vector ??

Comment: Numerical resolution raises no issue. There are well-known methods (Runge-Kutta) and your equation has no singularities.

Comment: The air friction term should always give a force opposite the current movement direction, which would give the form $...+b\,|u'|\,u'+...$. Using your form might give unphysical results in the numerical simulation. -- As far as I know, the best one has on the analytical side is one first integral for the ballistic shot (general free fall, $c=d=0$) with air friction.

Comment: Why does this have a PDE tag? And why are you writing $|u’|^2$ instead of $(u’)^2$?